# Limit field length when querying Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way to limit a field to a certain number of characters when getting results from Elasticsearch? I know how to limit my results to a specific set of fields, but I don't see how to get just a piece of the data. I would like to receive just the first 100 characters to display a preview of data and limit I/O.

I have seen that highlighting gives the option of setting a fragment size, but I am not necessarily querying for anything from the field I want a substring of.

Comment: I don't think there is such a feature in es that lets you specify a substring of a field. But you can probably index the first 100 characters together with the original field. You can then use source filtering to exclude the original field in `_source` [ref here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html). Or you can even exclude the original field completely at index time, [see here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-source-field.html#include-exclude)

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch doesn't provide such an option. The ideal way to achieve this kind of scenario is to change the way you are indexing data and may be store a snippet along with the long length fields.  ( @foresightyj has provided good links to exclude/include fields at indexing/querying time)