# How can I make ElasticSearch yield just the first couple of words for a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to query a set of rather long documents. Each document has (among other things) a title, a URL and a body.

When presenting the results to the user, I'd like to present just an 'abstract' of each document (along with the title and the URL). However, returning the full body only to trim it client-side seems wasteful.

Alas, I don't have a dedicated 'abstract' field or the like.  Hence I wonder: is there a way to make ElasticSearch yield just the beginning (e.g. the first 200 words) of the 'body' field for each hit? I looked at [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-source-filtering.html) (which I'm already using in my queries) but that seems to just select/deselect individual fields for the response. I'm rather looking for a way to transform the returned data.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25635811/limit-field-length-when-querying-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [Script Fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-script-fields.html) are one way to solve this. Here is an example query which gets the `title`, `uri` and a scripted(!) `abstract` field for each document. The `abstract` consists of the firsts 200 letters of the actual `content` field:

```js
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": "Scripting"
        },
    },
    "_source": ["title", "uri"],
    "script_fields": {
        "abstract": {
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "params['_source'].content.substring(0, 200)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a while to figure out the term for a calculated field. I was expecting names like *computed* or *derived*, but *script* was not too intuitive. Maybe this comments help others to find this post, too :-)